# Convert and optimize materials for WebGL automatically

Tags: materials, webgl

(materials newbie here)

I understand and appreciate that materials conversion for various use cases is an art, and I want to convert complex materials for use in SketchFab. That is - basically WebGL with additional constraints explained [here](https://github.com/sketchfab/blender-plugin#export-a-model-to-sketchfab)

However I need to maintain a large library, and manual conversions are too time consuming and just stripping down nodes until something that converts ok won't necessarily work in an aesthetically correct way.

Are there tools that would optimize an a conversion to within a certain tolerance in an automated way?

Example of complex material (maybe it's just complex to me:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to bake your materials into textures, have you explored that area of Blender ?

Comment: Yes, though not enough for sure. But I suspect in some cases textures might be too blunt an instrument: I could keep roughness, metallic, normal map cross both. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can bake pretty much every map that's listed in the bake dropdown, and even make your own by using the output of your shader. The main problem in your case is that it's very time consuming and you need to re-bake the materials again if you make changes to the procedural shader in blender. But there is next to no-interoperability in terms of procedural materials between softwares, so you don't really have a choice...